# Windows 8.1 Preview Pane stopped working

Tags: windows-8.1

I recently upgraded to Windows 8.1 and ... it is adjusting. After a while the preview pane in file explorer doesn't preview anymore. First I tried the basic suggestions on the web, but nothing really worked. Then I came around the following registry hack:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\DetailsContainer]
"DetailsContainer"=hex:02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer]
"DetailsContainerSizer"=hex:24,01,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2b,03,00,00
```

Which does work. The problem is, after logging in again (or rebooting) Windows seem to have forgotten about this setting completely. Of course you can always apply this again, but there got to be a away to make this permanent. Do you have any suggestions ?